# Why aren't the images getting changed every 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, css

```
let i = 0;

function change() {
  if (i < res.length) document.getElementById("cont").style.backgroundImage = `url(static/letters/${res[i++]}.jpg)`;
}
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(change, 2000);
};
```

I want this change only once till all the images get displayed and then want the container empty. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the value of `res`?

Comment: res is a string

Comment: And where/when/how is it defined?

Comment: var res = "";
        function rec(){
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
      recognition.lang = 'en-IN';
            recognition.onresult = function(event){
   document.getElementById("speechToText").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
   res = document.getElementById("speechToText").value;
      }
      recognition.start();
       }

Comment: @TanishaSethi Could be better if you edit your question with more detail and formatting  :)

Comment: Check the developer tool to see if the element's style is being updated, if the url of the image is loading etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this implementation

```js
let i = 0;

let interval //the variable to keep the current interval

//simulate your `res` data 
const res = [
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612151855475-877969f4a6cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80",
  "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg"
]

function change() {
  if (i < res.length) {
    document.getElementById("cont").style.backgroundImage = `url(${res[i++]})`;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cont").style.backgroundImage = "none";
    clearInterval(interval); //remove the current interval after finish the loop
    i = 0; //reset index value
  }

}
window.onload = function() {
  interval = setInterval(change, 2000); //set the current interval
};
```

```css
#cont {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: i did exactly the same but it's still not working :(

Comment: I think you should check your `res` data in `console.log` to make sure it's correct. If  `res` is as your expected, you can concern about the loading time, some images are loaded slowly (perhaps over 2 seconds) that may skip some of your image loadings @TanishaSethi

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job :

```
if (i < res.length) document.getElementById("cont").style.backgroundImage = `url('static/letters/${res[i++]}.jpg')`;
```

Comment: just tried, nope it didn't work :(